# Power Automate HTTP Request POST ends with "Internal Server Error"

Tags: httprequest, power-automate

I'm not sure why I face an **"Internal Server Error"** when I send an POST Request with Power Automate, but if I send the same request with Postman it works just fine. As you can see the flow tried 4 times until it stopped. I call the same REST API with Postman and it works without problems. The Authorization is by the way **Basic** with Username and Password.

[image: Internal Server Error]

[image: POST Request]

This is the response from Postman when I send the POST request:

```
{
"executionTime": 3360,
"hints": [
    {
        "id": "STRING",
        "name": "STRING",
        "type": "GROUP_HINT",
        "locations": [
            {
                "tokens": [
                    {
                        "start": 33,
                        "end": 41
                    },
                    {
                        "start": 61,
                        "end": 66
                    }
                ],
                "score": 1.0,
                "distance": 0,
                "groupValue": {
                    "left": "STRING",
                    "right": "STRING"
                }
            }
        ],
        "groupElement": [
            "MATCHED GROUPS"
        ],
        "range": 20
    }
],
"businessCases": [
    {
        "businessCaseId": "ee05f8f9-e18d-4bf7-b7db-4c8bc800615a",
        "name": "STRING",
        "score": 0.53,
        "hintCount": 1596,
        "originCount": 241,
        "matchedHints": [
            "MATCHED GROUPS"
        ],
        "matchedBoostedHints": [
            "MATCHED GROUPS"
        ],
        "origins": [],
        "matchedOrigins": [
            "MATCHED GROUPS"
        ],
        "matchedBoostedOrigins": [
            "MATCHED GROUPS"
        ],
        "unmatchedOrigins": []
    }
],
"questions": [],
"extractedValues": []
```

}

The REST API should analyse the text in the POST request and return any matched groups through sentiment analysis.

Comment: It sounds like your issue is with the API call to this DeepSearch API rather than with Power Automate. Can you include the information from Postman that results in a successful connection test?

Comment: Do you have a timeout or internal server error? Internal Server Error is a response from the backend. Can it be that you are missing some headers?

Comment: I'm a little confused looking at the site because it appears to be an Austrian TLD, but the website is in English, yet the API (at least its documentation) seems designed exclusively for Korean consumption. Is this a legitimate service?

Comment: It is an internal server error. I added the stop after 1 minute because otherwise it runs forever. Yes, the service is legitimate. It's used for sentiment text analysis.

Comment: Are you sure, the requests are *exactly* the same? Same headers, same data, same authentication?

Comment: Yeah. Both Requests are identically in the information I send. Just one is send from Postman and one from Power Automate.